# delete object[element] doesn't deletes but sets it to null ....how do I delete it instead of making it null?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

```
Object.keys(tours).forEach(el => {
    if (tours[el].id == 0) ***delete tours[el];***

  });
```

I want to delete and Object inside my Tours object but this unction sets it to null instead of deleting it.

tours before delete operation is like this

```
[
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "The Forest Hiker",
    "duration": 5,
    "maxGroupSize": 25,
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.7
},
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Sea Explorer",
    "duration": 7,
    "maxGroupSize": 15,
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.8
  }
]
```

and after delete it becomes

```
[
 null,

  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Sea Explorer",
    "duration": 7,
    "maxGroupSize": 15,
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.8,
    "ratingsQuantity": 23,
    "price": 497,
    "summary": "Exploring the jaw-dropping US east coast by foot and by boat",
    "description": "Cpariatur.",
    "imageCover": "tour-2-cover.jpg",
    "images": ["tour-2-1.jpg", "tour-2-2.jpg", "tour-2-3.jpg"],
    "startDates": ["2021-06-19,10:00", "2021-07-20,10:00", "2021-08-18,10:00"]
  }
]
```

Comment: Seems like you want [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) maybe?: `const res = tours.filter(obj => obj.id !== 0)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see `tours`  is just array of objects. so you can do:

*to delete by any condition*

```
tours = tours.filter(t => t.id !== 0);
```

*to delete given index `n`*

```
tours.splice(n, 1)
```

*to delete specifically the index `0`*

```
tours.shift()
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `delete` to remove elements from an array.

You can use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove elements from an array.

```
tours.forEach( (el, index) => {
 if (tours[el].id == 0) tours.splice(index, 1)
});
```

If the condition is true for more than one element in the array you need to take into account that you are mutating the array while iterating over it and so need to take into account the number of elements that where deleted.

```
deletedCount = 0

Object.keys(tours).forEach( (el, index) => {
  if(tours[el-deletedCount].id == 2 ) { 
   tours.splice(index-deletedCount, 1); 
   deletedCount++ 
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

### Removing multiple items

If the array can contain multiple values that you want to remove then you can use a function like [`Array#reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight) to iterate through the array from the end to the start (if you go the other and remove items the indexes of some items will change).

```js
var tours = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "The Forest Hiker",
  "duration": 5,
  "maxGroupSize": 25,
  "difficulty": "easy",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.7
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "The Sea Explorer",
  "duration": 7,
  "maxGroupSize": 15,
  "difficulty": "medium",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.8
}];

tours.reduceRight(function(res, item, index) {
  if (item.id === 0) tours.splice(index, 1);
}, 0);

console.log(tours);
```

### Removing 0-1 items

If the item with `id === 0` can only occur 0 to 1 times then you can just use:

```js
var tours = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "The Forest Hiker",
  "duration": 5,
  "maxGroupSize": 25,
  "difficulty": "easy",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.7
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "The Sea Explorer",
  "duration": 7,
  "maxGroupSize": 15,
  "difficulty": "medium",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.8
}];

var index = tours.findIndex(function(item) {
  return item.id === 0;
});
if (index !== -1) tours.splice(index, 1);

console.log(tours);
```

### Creating a new array with the correct items

Finally if you don't care about changing the array reference you could just use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var tours = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "The Forest Hiker",
  "duration": 5,
  "maxGroupSize": 25,
  "difficulty": "easy",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.7
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "name": "The Sea Explorer",
  "duration": 7,
  "maxGroupSize": 15,
  "difficulty": "medium",
  "ratingsAverage": 4.8
}];

tours = tours.filter(function(item) {
  return item.id !== 0;
});

console.log(tours);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to iterate an `array` like you would with an `object`, you can get a filtered array using `Array.filter` without mutating the original array.

```
filteredTours = tours.filter(tour => tour.id == 0)
```

you could also do this using splice,

```
tours.forEach((tour,index)=> if(tour.id===1){ tours.splice(index,1) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys()  is used to iterate Object's props. Here you'd better to use for loop or forEach directly. When you find the matched one, just splice it. Any help?

```
for (let i = 0; i < tours.length; i++) {
  if (tours[i].id === 0) {
    return tours.splice(i, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I made this trick and it worked, but its use is up to you.**

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "The Forest Hiker",
    "duration": 5,
    "maxGroupSize": 25,
    "difficulty": "easy",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.7
},
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "The Sea Explorer",
    "duration": 7,
    "maxGroupSize": 15,
    "difficulty": "medium",
    "ratingsAverage": 4.8
  }
];
console.log("BEFORE: ", myArray);
delete myArray[0];
console.log("AFTER (with NULL): ", myArray);
const newArray = JSON.stringify(myArray).replaceAll("null,", "").replaceAll("null", "").replaceAll("empty,", "").replaceAll("empty", "")
console.log("AFTER (without NULL): ", newArray, JSON.stringify(newArray));
```